# Computing expectation when absolute values are involved

Tags: probability, expected-value

I don't understand how to algebraically approach expected value problems that include absolute values. Let's take a very simple example:

Find $E(|X_1 - X_2|)$, where $X1, X2$ ~ $U(0,1)$ and are independent.

I understand that I should split these up into two cases, where $X_1 < X_2$ and where $X_1 > X_2$, and then compute something like

$ \int_{0}^{1}(1 - P(|X_1-X_2| > z))dz$

How do I split those cases up in a context like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Just start from first principles:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_{1}-X_{2}\right|\right]
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left|x_{1}-x_{2}\right|dx_{2}dx_{1}
=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{x_{1}}x_{1}-x_{2}dx_{2}+\int_{x_{1}}^{1}x_{2}-x_{1}dx_{2}\right)dx_{1}.
$$

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!